# How to access to multi-level dict python with iterators?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I have this dict/json:

```
data={
"paraview": {
    "3.5": {
        "image": "/data/singularity/containers/paraview_5.5.2.simg",
        "recipe": "/data/singularity/YAJE/yaje/paraview/Singularity.5.5.2",
        "source": "packet"
    },
    "5.5.2": {
        "image": "/data/singularity/containers/paraview_5.5.2.simg",
        "recipe": "/data/singularity/YAJE/yaje/paraview/Singularity.5.5.2",
        "source": "packet"
    }
  }
}
```

I can found a value with:

```
app ="paraview"
version= "3.5"

if app in data:
   if version in data[app]:
       print("ubucacion: {}".format(data[app][version]['image']))
```

output:

```
ubucacion: /data/singularity/containers/paraview_5.5.2.simg
```

But, How I can do it with iteratos for very big dicts?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean i would be happy to help though, do you want to loop through sevral quaries

Comment: @JonasWolff, what I need is to make a single query, with some fixed values, but I am afraid that if the dictionary grows a lot it has problems in response time. that's why I thought I should do something more efficient

Comment: dicionary uses hashes so i don't think size is a real issue

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
for i in [(app,version), (app,version)]:
    if i[0] in data and i[1] in data[i[0]]: # secondhalf of and statement won't run if first half is false
        print("ubucacion: {}".format(data[i[0]][i[1]]['image']))
```